# Using adaptive step sizes with scipy.integrate.ode

Tags: python, scipy, ode

The (brief) documentation for `scipy.integrate.ode` says that two methods (`dopri5` and `dop853`) have stepsize control and dense output.  Looking at the examples and the code itself, I can only see a very simple way to get output from an integrator.  Namely, it looks like you just step the integrator forward by some fixed dt, get the function value(s) at that time, and repeat.

My problem has pretty variable timescales, so I'd like to just get the values at whatever time steps it needs to evaluate to achieve the required tolerances.  That is, early on, things are changing slowly, so the output time steps can be big.  But as things get interesting, the output time steps have to be smaller.  I don't actually want dense output at equal intervals, I just want the time steps the adaptive function uses.

## EDIT: Dense output

A related notion (almost the opposite) is "dense output", whereby the steps taken are as large as the stepper cares to take, but the values of the function are interpolated (usually with accuracy comparable to the accuracy of the stepper) to whatever you want.  The fortran underlying `scipy.integrate.ode` is apparently capable of this, but `ode` does not have the interface.  `odeint`, on the other hand, is based on a different code, and does evidently do dense output.  (You can output every time your right-hand-side is called to see when that happens, and see that it has nothing to do with the output times.)

So I could still take advantage of adaptivity, as long as I could decide on the output time steps I want ahead of time.  Unfortunately, for my favorite system, I don't even know what the approximate timescales are as functions of time, until I run the integration.  So I'll have to combine the idea of taking one integrator step with this notion of dense output.

## EDIT 2: Dense output again

Apparently, scipy 1.0.0 introduced support for dense output through a new interface.  In particular, they recommend moving away from `scipy.integrate.odeint` and towards [`scipy.integrate.solve_ivp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html), which as a keyword `dense_output`.  If set to `True`, the returned object has an attribute `sol` that you can call with an array of times, which then returns the integrated functions values at those times.  That still doesn't solve the problem for this question, but it is useful in many cases.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since [SciPy 0.13.0](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/release.0.13.0.html),

> The intermediate results from the `dopri` family of ODE solvers can
>   now be accessed by a `solout` callback function.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import ode
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def logistic(t, y, r):
    return r * y * (1.0 - y)

r = .01
t0 = 0
y0 = 1e-5
t1 = 5000.0

backend = 'dopri5'
# backend = 'dop853'
solver = ode(logistic).set_integrator(backend)

sol = []
def solout(t, y):
    sol.append([t, *y])
solver.set_solout(solout)
solver.set_initial_value(y0, t0).set_f_params(r)
solver.integrate(t1)

sol = np.array(sol)

plt.plot(sol[:,0], sol[:,1], 'b.-')
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image: Logistic function solved using DOPRI5]

The result seems to be slightly different from Tim D's, although they both use the same backend. I suspect this having to do with FSAL property of `dopri5`. In Tim's approach, I think the result k7 from the seventh stage is discarded, so k1 is calculated afresh.

Note: There's a known [bug with set_solout not working if you set it after setting initial values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26738676/does-scipy-integrate-ode-set-solout-work). It was fixed as of [SciPy 0.17.0](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/release.0.17.0.html).

Comment: Keep in mind that for now (version 0.16) you have to call `set_solout()` **before** `set_initial_value()` or solout won't be called.

Comment: @syockit I have tried the above method (dopri5 and vode) and I am finding that the results are not deterministic. Meaning that for my, stiff, set of ODEs, sometimes the algorithm completes successfully and sometimes it fails (given the same inputs).
This does not work for me. Do you know how to force this to be deterministic, or where else I might look for a deterministic solution? Thanks.

Comment: @theJollySin Sorry for the late reply. Unfortunately, the choice of stable algorithm depends much on the domain of the problem, so I can't give you a good one-size-fits-all advice. The current documentation for scipy.integrate.ode tells you which one to use or what to do when dealing with stiff problems.

Answer (score 14):

I've been looking at this to try to get the same result. It turns out you can use a hack to get the step-by-step results by setting nsteps=1 in the ode instantiation. It will generate a UserWarning at every step (this can be caught and suppressed).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import ode
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import warnings


def logistic(t, y, r):
    return r * y * (1.0 - y)

r = .01
t0 = 0
y0 = 1e-5
t1 = 5000.0

#backend = 'vode'
backend = 'dopri5'
#backend = 'dop853'

solver = ode(logistic).set_integrator(backend, nsteps=1)
solver.set_initial_value(y0, t0).set_f_params(r)
# suppress Fortran-printed warning
solver._integrator.iwork[2] = -1

sol = []
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning)
while solver.t < t1:
    solver.integrate(t1, step=True)
    sol.append([solver.t, solver.y])
warnings.resetwarnings()
sol = np.array(sol)

plt.plot(sol[:,0], sol[:,1], 'b.-')
plt.show()
```

result:
[image]

Comment: That seems to do the job, alright.  Now, if only I hadn't spent weeks porting my code to GSL...  :)

Comment: It turns out you can suppress the Fortran-emitted warning with this little hack `solver._integrator.iwork[2] = -1` (I'll edit the above code to show this). This sets a flag passed through the Fortran interface that suppresses printing to stdout.

Answer (score 8):

The `integrate` method accepts a boolean argument `step` that tells the method to return a single internal step.  However, it appears that the 'dopri5' and 'dop853' solvers do not support it.

The following code shows how you can get the internal steps taken by the solver when the 'vode' solver is used:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import ode
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def logistic(t, y, r):
    return r * y * (1.0 - y)

r = .01

t0 = 0
y0 = 1e-5
t1 = 5000.0

backend = 'vode'
#backend = 'dopri5'
#backend = 'dop853'
solver = ode(logistic).set_integrator(backend)
solver.set_initial_value(y0, t0).set_f_params(r)

sol = []
while solver.successful() and solver.t < t1:
    solver.integrate(t1, step=True)
    sol.append([solver.t, solver.y])

sol = np.array(sol)

plt.plot(sol[:,0], sol[:,1], 'b.-')
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image: Plot of the solution]

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid that was the case.  I was hoping that there'd be an easy way to extend `dopri5` and `dop853`, but my patience ends at fortran, so I think I'll just re-implement a time stepper.  Seems a shame, though, that python is left without robust, efficient, and flexible integrators...

Comment: I needed this same functionality while trying to convert a MATLAB script that uses ode45. I've submitted a ticket at Scipy.org [Ticket#1820](http://projects.scipy.org/scipy/ticket/1820).

Comment: @Mike: Well, even with `dopri5` and `dop853` you could always store the value from inside the `logistic` function and just do a single call to the `integrate` method. (I'm going to post this as alternative answer.)

Comment: On another note: I like it how the `step=True` feature [isn't documented at all](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.integrate.html#scipy.integrate.ode.integrate).

Comment: @Mike Please see my note below about PyDSTool's native support for dense output and internal steps using dopri 853.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, although an answer has been accepted already, I should point out for the historical record that dense output and arbitrary sampling from *anywhere* along the computed trajectory is natively supported in [PyDSTool](http://pydstool.sf.net). This also includes a record of all the adaptively-determined time steps used internally by the solver. This interfaces with both [dopri853 and radau5](http://www.ni.gsu.edu/~rclewley/PyDSTool/Generators.html) and auto-generates the C code necessary to interface with them rather than relying on (much slower) python function callbacks for the right-hand side definition. None of these features are natively or efficiently provided in any other python-focused solver, to my knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

Here's another option that should also work with `dopri5` and `dop853`. Basically, the solver will call the `logistic()` function as often as needed to calculate intermediate values so that's where we store the results:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import ode
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sol = []
def logistic(t, y, r):
    sol.append([t, y])
    return r * y * (1.0 - y)

r = .01

t0 = 0
y0 = 1e-5
t1 = 5000.0
# Maximum number of steps that the integrator is allowed 
# to do along the whole interval [t0, t1].
N = 10000

#backend = 'vode'
backend = 'dopri5'
#backend = 'dop853'
solver = ode(logistic).set_integrator(backend, nsteps=N)
solver.set_initial_value(y0, t0).set_f_params(r)

# Single call to solver.integrate()
solver.integrate(t1)
sol = np.array(sol)

plt.plot(sol[:,0], sol[:,1], 'b.-')
plt.show()
```

Comment: There are three time steps involved here.  The largest is the output time step; what `ode` outputs by default.  Then we have the integrator's adaptive time step, which is where I want the output.  The smallest is the intermediate time step that Runge-Kutta-style integrators (e.g., `dopri5`, `dop853`) use.  That is, `dopri5` will actually call `logistic` several times during intermediate steps taken to make up a single time step.  My concern is that I believe those intermediate steps have lower-order accuracy; the `y` value is actually only first-order accurate in many cases.

Comment: "I believe those intermediate steps have lower-order accuracy" Oops, I thought `logistic` would be called with the integrator's adaptive time step. If not, my answer of course doesn't help. But are sure about that?

Comment: The idea is to build up better approximations to the correct increment; combining the results of multiple calls allows you to cancel some error terms.  In fact, now that I look at it, Wikipedia's article has a section explaining ["*The* Runge-Kutta method"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods#The_Runge.E2.80.93Kutta_method), in which it shows that the function is evaluated at the step-midpoint twice with different values.  So your `sol` would actually be storing two different `y` values for the same `t` value in some cases, because the first was less accurate.