# Stepsize control of dopri5 integrator

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ode

I am trying to solve a simple example with the `dopri5` integrator in `scipy.integrate.ode`. As the documentation states

> This is an explicit runge-kutta method of order (4)5 due to Dormand & Prince (with stepsize control and dense output).

this should work. So here is my example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import ode
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def MassSpring_with_force(t, state):
    """ Simple 1DOF dynamics model: m ddx(t) + k x(t) = f(t)"""
    # unpack the state vector
    x = state[0]
    xd = state[1]

    # these are our constants
    k = 2.5 # Newtons per metre
    m = 1.5 # Kilograms

    # force
    f = force(t)

    # compute acceleration xdd
    xdd = ( ( -k*x + f) / m )

    # return the two state derivatives
    return [xd, xdd]


def force(t):
    """ Excitation force """
    f0 = 1  # force amplitude [N]
    freq = 20  # frequency[Hz]
    omega = 2 * np.pi *freq  # angular frequency [rad/s]
    return f0 * np.sin(omega*t)


# Time range
t_start = 0
t_final = 1

# Main program
state_ode_f = ode(MassSpring_with_force)

state_ode_f.set_integrator('dopri5', rtol=1e-6, nsteps=500,
                       first_step=1e-6, max_step=1e-3)

state2 = [0.0, 0.0]  # initial conditions
state_ode_f.set_initial_value(state2, 0)

sol = np.array([[t_start, state2[0], state2[1]]], dtype=float)

print("Time\t\t Timestep\t dx\t\t ddx\t\t state_ode_f.successful()")

while state_ode_f.t < (t_final):
    state_ode_f.integrate(t_final, step=True)
    sol = np.append(sol, [[state_ode_f.t, state_ode_f.y[0], state_ode_f.y[1]]], axis=0)
    print("{0:0.8f}\t {1:0.4e} \t{2:10.3e}\t {3:0.3e}\t {4}".format(
            state_ode_f.t, sol[-1, 0]- sol[-2, 0], state_ode_f.y[0], state_ode_f.y[1], state_ode_f.successful()))
```

The result I get is:

```
Time         Timestep    dx      ddx         state_ode_f.successful()
0.49763822   4.9764e-01      2.475e-03   -8.258e-04  False
0.99863822   5.0100e-01      3.955e-03   -3.754e-03  False
1.00000000   1.3618e-03      3.950e-03   -3.840e-03  False
```

with a warning:

> c:\python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate_ode.py:1018: UserWarning: dopri5: larger nmax is needed
>     self.messages.get(idid, 'Unexpected idid=%s' % idid))

The result is incorect. If I run the same code with `vode` integrator, I get the expected result.

**Edit**

A similar issue is described here: 
[Using adaptive step sizes with scipy.integrate.ode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926393/using-adaptive-step-sizes-with-scipy-integrate-ode)

The suggested solution recommends setting `nsteps=1`, which solves the ODE correctly and with step-size control. However the integrator returns `state_ode_f.successful()` as `False`.

Comment: possible duplicate (identified by blaz) in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926393/using-adaptive-step-sizes-with-scipy-integrate-ode

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing wrong. You are telling the integrator to perform an integration step to `t_final` and it performs that step. Internal steps of the integrator are not reported.

---

The sensible thing to do is to give the desired sampling points as input of the algorithm, set for example `dt=0.1` and use

```
state_ode_f.integrate( min(state_ode_f.t+dt, t_final) )
```

There is no single-`step` method in `dopri5`, only `vode` has it defined, see the source code https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/integrate/_ode.py#L376, this could account for the observed differences.

As you found in [Using adaptive step sizes with scipy.integrate.ode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926393/using-adaptive-step-sizes-with-scipy-integrate-ode), one can force single-step behavior by setting the iteration bound `nsteps=1`. This will produce a warning every time, so one has to suppress these specific warnings to see a sensible result.

---

You should not use a parameter (which is a constant for the integration interval) for a time-dependent force. Use inside `MassSpring_with_force` the evaluation `f=force(t)`. Possibly you could pass the function handle of `force` as parameter.

Comment: Hey LutzL thank you for your anwser. I set the evaluation of `f=force(t)`inside the `MassSpring_with_force`. However if you try running the code it still does not work. If you chose i.e. the `vode` integrator, the integration process runs as expected.

Comment: Set `rtol=1e-12`, it is possible that the indicated stepsize is sufficient for `rtol=1e-6` in the order 5 dopri5 method.

Comment: I still get three iterations.

Comment: Try increasing `nsteps`, as that is the complaint in the warning. However, 500 inner iteration steps would relate to a too small step size for any tame problem.

Comment: Here is a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926393/using-adaptive-step-sizes-with-scipy-integrate-ode

Comment: setting the `dt` as you recommended works, but this makes a constant step-size

Comment: And does the method in the similar question of setting `nsteps=1` and suppressing the warnings work for you?

Comment: Yes, this works. However, the `state_ode_f.successful()` is always `False`.

Comment: Yes of course it is false. You are preventing the algorithm to reach the requested end time `t_final`, it is a hack, an inefficient one as it is with all the back'n'forth from python to fortran. But if it works for you, it is fine.